# Only the world is being rendered

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation

I get essentially a black screen when rendering or the colour of the world, I ran a fluid simulation and it looks fine in the rendered view but doing the final render gives no result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Cube and Cube.001 are hidden during rendering.
Second, the material of both Cube and Cube.001 is undefined which leads to black during rendering. Delete the Material and assign a new one, for example a diffuse shader for testing.

[image]

Changing the settings like described, I get the following result:

[image]

(OK, I also changed the position of the lamp a little bit, but nothing else)

If you want to see a "real" preview you have to activate this button:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for answering, just one more question; why does it not happen in rendered view?

Comment: Instead of multiple answers edit this one, they don't seem to differ quite much. As to the render result most likely the animation wasn't played and water domain is shown